# What's the special meaning of '-' in Zsh?

Tags: zsh

In bash I have

```
$ echo -e -
-
$
```

But I get this in zsh:

```
$ echo '-'

$ print '-'

$
```

It seems that this is no substitution like that of `~`, etc.

Is this feature documented somewhere? And what is the simplest way to print a single `-` character if I want to do that?

Comment: `printf %s -` will print a `-`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann It worked. Thank you:-)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a single `-` has no special meaning in `zsh`. But this is specific to `zsh` insofar that `echo` and `print` are both built-ins of `zsh` (`echo` is also a built-in of `bash`, but behaves slightly different there - obviously).

A single `-` denotes that any arguments following it are not to be handled as options. This allows for example to output `-E` with `echo` instead enforcing BSD style `echo` behavior:

```
% echo -E 'f\x6f\x6fbar'
f\x6f\x6fbar
% echo - -E 'f\x6f\x6fbar'
foobar
```

For `print` this is documented in the [`zshbuiltins` manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print). Unfortunatelly it seems to be undocumented for `echo`.

Following this, the easiest way to output a single `-` (in `zsh`) is probably to pass two of it to `echo` or `print`:

```
% echo - -
-
% print - -
-
```

The first `-` also disables parsing any further `-` as options.

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf` is more portable and will work more reliable than `echo`. Try

```
$ printf '%s\n' -
-
```

Comment: But I still have no idea why `echo` should behave like this... I read [zsh's document](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) but it didn't mention this.

Comment: Good answer! @八重垣えりか I don't think that `zsh` is behaving correctly here.

Comment: Bah, all my previous comments are wrong. I'll just note that `-` by itself *is* documented as a flag for `print`, but there is no mention of any such flag for `echo`.

Comment: I beg to differ @chepner, the zshall man page says (in 5.5.1 at least) "Note that for standards compliance a double dash does not terminate option processing; instead, it is printed directly.  However, a single dash does terminate option processing, so the first dash, possibly following options, is not  printed,  but  everything  following  it  is printed  as an argument.  The single dash behaviour is different from other shells.  For a more portable way of printing text, see printf, and for a more controllable way of printing text within zsh, see print."